# Use another Datasource with tyeorm in an inherited class

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I aim to implement an audit log for my PostgreSQL database using TypeORM. I want to create a class named "`_Demo`" that inherits from another class called "`Demo`." Both classes have identical properties. However, I intend to use "`_Demo`" to represent the same model but in a different database, utilizing a distinct data source.

In simpler terms, I'm extending the "`Demo`" class to create a new class, "`_Demo`," which mirrors its properties. The key distinction is that I plan to use "_Demo" to interact with a separate database through a different data source.

It is already working when using the same datasource

Here is how i connect to the datasource

```js
await AuditDataSource.dataSourceConnection.connect();
        if (dataSourceOptions.synchronize) {
            await AuditDataSource.dataSourceConnection.sync(
                false);
```

Here are my datasource options:

```js
      private static connectionOptions: DataSourceOptions = {
        type: "postgres",
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
        username: process.env.DB_USER,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE_NAME,
        entities: [
          process.env.NODE_ENV === "build"
            ? process.env.BUILD_MODEL_PATH
            : process.env.DEV_MODEL_PATH,
        ],
        synchronize: true,
        logging: true,
      };
```

Here is my model `Demo`. At the botton you can find that `_Demo` inherits from the class `Demo`

```js
    @Entity()
    @Expose()
    export class Demo {
        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
        uuid: string;
    
        @Expose()
        @Column()
        demoName: string;
    }
    
    @AuditEntity(Demo, {
        seqType: "int",
        specificFields: ["demoEmail", "demoBoolean"]
    })
    export class _Demo extends Demo {}
```

This is not the complete code from the class `AuditEntity` but here i want to use the other datasouerce. Now it is using the datasource you can see above

```js
export function AuditEntity<T extends ObjectLiteral>(entityType: { new(): T }, options?: AuditEntityOptions) {
    return (target: Function) => {
        options = options || {};

...

        metadata.tables.push({
            target,
            name: entityOptions.name,
            type: 'regular',
            orderBy: entityOptions.orderBy || origin.orderBy,
            engine: entityOptions.engine || origin.engine,
            database: con.database,
            schema: entityOptions.schema || origin.schema,
            synchronize: entityOptions.synchronize || origin.synchronize,
            withoutRowid: entityOptions.withoutRowid,
        } as TableMetadataArgs);


...
```

}